# GridDB Error 10008 TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH on WSL

Tags: cluster-computing, windows-subsystem-for-linux, griddb

I am currently facing an issue while executing a client request in GridDB, and I'm receiving the error code "10008 TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH." This error occurs

```
        GridStoreFactory factory = GridStoreFactory.getInstance();
    

        try (GridStore store = factory.getGridStore(props)) {

            // Create a TimeSeries container (replace "your_container_name" with your actual container name)
            String containerName = "your_container_name";
            TimeSeries<String> ts = store.putTimeSeries(containerName, String.class);

            // Prepare data for insertion
            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String data = "Sample Data";

            // Insert data into the TimeSeries container
            ts.put(timestamp, data);

            // Retrieve data from the TimeSeries container
            Row<String> row = ts.get(timestamp);
            System.out.println("Retrieved data: " + row.getValue());

        } catch (GSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm currently utilizing a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE.”

In an attempt to resolve this issue, I have tried executing a gs_joincluster command to ensure the cluster is in a constituted state.

```
gs_joincluster -u admin -w adminpass -c myCluster -s 192.168.0.1 -p 10001
```

Despite performing the gs_joincluster action, the problem persists. I'm reaching out to the community for insights into potential causes and additional steps to resolve the "TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH" error.